# Count all Excel cells with a certain color

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count all cells with a specific color in Excel.
I have written the code below but it does not count the cells highlighted by conditional formatting.
Would you have any ideas how to do that?
Thanks in advance!

```
Function CountByColor(rg As Range, RefColorCell As Range) As Long
'Counts cells colored manually, whether hidden by a filter or not. _
    Does not count cells colored by conditional formatting! _
    Install function in a regular module sheet, just like a recorded macro.
Dim cel As Range, rgg As Range
Dim i As Long, RefColor As Long
RefColor = RefColorCell.Interior.Color
Application.Volatile
Set rgg = Intersect(rg, rg.Worksheet.UsedRange)     'In case you passed an entire column
For Each cel In rgg.Cells
    If cel.Interior.Color = RefColor Then i = i + 1
Next
CountByColor = i
End Function
```

Comment: Not really, I tried writing: If cel.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RefColor Then i = i + 1 but it still isn't working

Comment: Are you using this Function as a UDF?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I can't get `.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` to work as a UDF, only a macro... Must be some limitation with using a UDF.

Comment: @pgSystemTester that's why I asked the OP. (The link you shared mention that, and offered an alternative- iterating the CF collection)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, this isn't easily accomplished as a CUSTOM function because the property `.cel.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` will not return a value as a function, however it will return a value when used as a macro.

To get what you need, you will need the below lengthty set of custom functions that I pulled from [Chip Pearson's legendary site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CFColors.htm). While it is excessive, I tested and it does work when I embedded it into your original function `CountByColor`.

[Sample file here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g6tU5mTsUVzPTBwe1Q?e=GaPhpb) (won't work on Web Version of Excel)

```
Function CountByColor(rg As Range, RefColorCell As Range) As Long
Dim cel As Range, rgg As Range, i As Long, RefColor As Long

RefColor = RefColorCell.Interior.Color
Application.Volatile
Set rgg = Intersect(rg, rg.Worksheet.UsedRange)
For Each cel In rgg.Cells
    If ColorOfCF(cel) = RefColor Then i = i + 1
Next
CountByColor = i
End Function

Private Function ActiveCondition(Rng As Range) As Long
Dim Ndx As Long, FC As FormatCondition
Dim Temp As Variant, Temp2 As Variant

If Rng.FormatConditions.Count = 0 Then
    ActiveCondition = 0
Else
    For Ndx = 1 To Rng.FormatConditions.Count
        Set FC = Rng.FormatConditions(Ndx)
        Select Case FC.Type
            Case xlCellValue
            Select Case FC.Operator
                Case xlBetween
                    Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                    Temp2 = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula2)
                    If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                       If CDbl(Rng.Value) >= CDbl(FC.Formula1) And _
                           CDbl(Rng.Value) <= CDbl(FC.Formula2) Then
                           ActiveCondition = Ndx
                           Exit Function
                       End If
                   Else
                      If Rng.Value >= Temp And _
                         Rng.Value <= Temp2 Then
                         ActiveCondition = Ndx
                         Exit Function
                      End If
                   End If

                Case xlGreater
                    Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                    If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                       If CDbl(Rng.Value) > CDbl(FC.Formula1) Then
                          ActiveCondition = Ndx
                          Exit Function
                       End If
                    Else
                       If Rng.Value > Temp Then
                          ActiveCondition = Ndx
                          Exit Function
                       End If
                    End If

                Case xlEqual
                    Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                    If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                       If CDbl(Rng.Value) = CDbl(FC.Formula1) Then
                           ActiveCondition = Ndx
                           Exit Function
                       End If
                    Else
                       If Temp = Rng.Value Then
                          ActiveCondition = Ndx
                          Exit Function
                       End If
                    End If


                Case xlGreaterEqual
                    Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                    If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                       If CDbl(Rng.Value) >= CDbl(FC.Formula1) Then
                           ActiveCondition = Ndx
                           Exit Function
                       End If
                    Else
                       If Rng.Value >= Temp Then
                          ActiveCondition = Ndx
                          Exit Function
                       End If
                    End If

              
                Case xlLess
                    Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                    If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                        If CDbl(Rng.Value) < CDbl(FC.Formula1) Then
                           ActiveCondition = Ndx
                           Exit Function
                        End If
                    Else
                        If Rng.Value < Temp Then
                           ActiveCondition = Ndx
                           Exit Function
                        End If
                    End If

                Case xlLessEqual
                    Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                    If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                       If CDbl(Rng.Value) <= CDbl(FC.Formula1) Then
                          ActiveCondition = Ndx
                          Exit Function
                       End If
                    Else
                       If Rng.Value <= Temp Then
                          ActiveCondition = Ndx
                          Exit Function
                       End If
                    End If


                Case xlNotEqual
                    Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                    If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                       If CDbl(Rng.Value) <> CDbl(FC.Formula1) Then
                          ActiveCondition = Ndx
                          Exit Function
                       End If
                    Else
                       If Temp <> Rng.Value Then
                          ActiveCondition = Ndx
                          Exit Function
                       End If
                    End If

               Case xlNotBetween
                    Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                    Temp2 = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula2)
                    If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                       If Not (CDbl(Rng.Value) <= CDbl(FC.Formula1)) And _
                          (CDbl(Rng.Value) >= CDbl(FC.Formula2)) Then
                          ActiveCondition = Ndx
                          Exit Function
                       End If
                    Else
                       If Not Rng.Value <= Temp And _
                          Rng.Value >= Temp2 Then
                          ActiveCondition = Ndx
                          Exit Function
                       End If
                    End If
            
               Case Else
                    Debug.Print "UNKNOWN OPERATOR"
           End Select


        Case xlExpression
            If Application.Evaluate(FC.Formula1) Then
               ActiveCondition = Ndx
               Exit Function
            End If

        Case Else
            Debug.Print "UNKNOWN TYPE"
       End Select

    Next Ndx

End If

ActiveCondition = 0

End Function
 


Private Function ColorOfCF(Rng As Range, Optional OfText As Boolean = False) As Long

Dim AC As Long
AC = ActiveCondition(Rng)
If AC = 0 Then
    If OfText = True Then
       ColorOfCF = Rng.Font.Color
    Else
       ColorOfCF = Rng.Interior.Color
    End If
Else
    If OfText = True Then
       ColorOfCF = Rng.FormatConditions(AC).Font.Color
    Else
       ColorOfCF = Rng.FormatConditions(AC).Interior.Color
    End If
End If

End Function

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Function GetStrippedValue(CF As String) As String
    Dim Temp As String
    If InStr(1, CF, "=", vbTextCompare) Then
       Temp = Mid(CF, 3, Len(CF) - 3)
       If Left(Temp, 1) = "=" Then
           Temp = Mid(Temp, 2)
       End If
    Else
       Temp = CF
    End If
    GetStrippedValue = Temp
End Function
```

Comment: Side note, while testing this, I wasted about 5 minutes trying to figure out why it wouldn't work if I changed the cell color of the comparison colored cell. That does NOT trigger the volatile recalc, so beware of that.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't seem to work on my computer, I get a #VALUE! error

Comment: Worth noting that Chip lists a number of caveats,  including that it won't work with Relative Range References.   That one seems like a deal breaker to me

Comment: @Loic what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Version 2105, I used the function as CountByColor(A1:A10,B1) with B1 the cell of the color I want to sum

Comment: @chrisneilsen, when embedding these functions into the original function, I don't think the relative matter is an issue.  You can download the version I was messing with here: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g6tU5mTsUVzPTBwe1Q?e=GaPhpb

Comment: Any idea why I might get an error while testing this?

Comment: Is there a way to gknow exactly what line gives the error? I just get a #VALUE! when I use the formula...

Comment: Also, the code above isn't working for me when I download the Excel file