# How to count color filled cells (regardless of text or blank) in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count the number of cells in a specific column that are filled with a specific color, as there can be multiple colors within one column. These cells can be empty or filled with text, and the excel guides I've found online aren't helping much as they can only count one or the other.
I found a VBA guide which suggested this code:

```
Function ColorCount(ColorCell As Range, DataRange As Range)

   Dim Data_Range As Range
   Dim Cell_Color As Long

   Cell_Color = ColorCell.Interior.ColorIndex

   For Each Data_Range In DataRange

   If Data_Range.Interior.ColorIndex = Cell_Color Then
   ColorCount = ColorCount + 1
   End If

   Next Data_Range

End Function
```

However, when I input this code and ran the =ColorCount function, every cell with any type of color was counted. Is there something I am doing wrong here? The specific function syntax I was told to follow is =ColorCount("cell with specific color as example","range of cells to count").

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68786105/count-all-excel-cells-with-a-certain-color?

Comment: Your code should work. Need to see data.

Comment: The original code in the question linked works, but when any changes are made to the cell color the count isn't automatically updated. Is there some additional piece that can be added so that the count automatically updates? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68786105/count-all-excel-cells-with-a-certain-color

Comment: OH. Use `worksheet_change`.

Comment: *Is there some additional piece that can be added so that the count automatically updates?* Make your UDF Volatile. https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/volatile-functions.html